# Send Ctrl Alt Del through INPUT Structure doesn't work?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, sendinput

How to simulate this ctrl alt del so that it will work ?

My code is as follows:

INPUT       Input;
/* Generate a "key down" */

```
Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE; 
Input.ki.wScan=29;
Input.ki.dwExtraInfo=0;
Input.ki.wVk=0;
Input.ki.time=0;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));


Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE; 
Input.ki.wScan=56;
Input.ki.dwExtraInfo=0;
Input.ki.wVk=0;
Input.ki.time=0;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));


Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE; 
Input.ki.wScan=83;
Input.ki.dwExtraInfo=0;
Input.ki.wVk=0;
Input.ki.time=0;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));


Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; 
Input.ki.wScan=29;
Input.ki.dwExtraInfo=0;
Input.ki.wVk=0;
Input.ki.time=0;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));


Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE  | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; 
Input.ki.wScan=56;
Input.ki.dwExtraInfo=0;
Input.ki.wVk=0;
Input.ki.time=0;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));


Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE  | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; 
Input.ki.wScan=83;
Input.ki.dwExtraInfo=0;
Input.ki.wVk=0;
Input.ki.time=0;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows XP, since SendSAS is not available:

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <winwlx.h>

#include <stdio.h>

BOOL CALLBACK parents(HWND hwnd, LPARAM dummy);

HWND saswindow = NULL;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

  HDESK h;

  HWINSTA hw;

  DWORD err;

  hw = OpenWindowStation("winsta0", FALSE, GENERIC_ALL);

  if (!hw) {

    printf("Error %u calling OpenWindowStation.\n", GetLastError());

    return 1;

  }

  if (!SetProcessWindowStation(hw)) {

    printf("Error %u calling SetProcessWindowStation.\n", GetLastError());

    return 1;

  }

  h = OpenDesktop("Winlogon", 0, FALSE, GENERIC_ALL);

  if (!h) {

    printf("Error %u calling OpenDesktop.\n", GetLastError());

    return 1;

  }

  if (!EnumDesktopWindows(h, parents, 0)) {

    err = GetLastError();

    if (err != 0) {

      printf("Error %u enumerating top-level windows.\n", err);

      return 1;

    }

  }

  if (saswindow == NULL) {

    printf("SAS window not found.\n");

    return 1;

  }

  if (!PostMessage(saswindow, WLX_WM_SAS, WLX_SAS_TYPE_CTRL_ALT_DEL, 0)) {

    printf("Error %u posting message.\n", GetLastError());

    return 1;

  }

  return 0;

}

BOOL CALLBACK parents(HWND hwnd, LPARAM dummy) {  

  static int n;

  static char wintext[16];

  n = GetWindowText(hwnd, wintext, sizeof(wintext));

  if (n == 0) return TRUE;

  if (strcmp(wintext, "SAS window") != 0) return TRUE;

  saswindow = hwnd;

  SetLastError(0);

  return FALSE;

}
```

Comment: it doesn't work and gives an "Error 5 calling OpenDesktop" which means access is denied.

Comment: On Windows XP when running as an administrator?

Comment: Ah, OK.  I probably never tried it except as a service, so that's quite possible.  Probably you need to be SYSTEM.

Answer (score 6):

CTRL+ALT+DEL is the secure attention sequence (SAS) and you can't fake it with `SendInput`. The [`SendSAS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979761.aspx) function is what you need to call.

However, this is only available on Windows 7. For older versions of Windows, if I recall correctly, you need to request a special library from MS in order to generate SAS. My memory is failing me, but I think it is called SASLIB. There is also a commercial product known as [SasLibEx](http://www.simulatesas.com/blog/tag/saslibex/) that does the job. Yet another avenue if you need to support older versions of Windows is to look at the source code for VNC to see how they do it.

Comment: An example of what? SendSAS is trivial. Just follow my link.

Comment: @David: it is possible to send an SAS in Windows XP, with a bit of hackery - see my answer.  Dunno about Vista.

Comment: The documentation for SendSAS implies that the Windows SDK includes sas.dll and that this can be used on Windows Vista.  It isn't entirely clear though.